# Python 3: Generate not all permutations, but all non-repetitive combinations of length r?

Tags: python, cryptography, iteration, lazy-evaluation, vigenere

I'm trying to generate a lazily iterable collection of Vigenere cipher keys of length r. I'm aware of `itertools` and the `permutations()` method. However, this generates keys such as `ABCD`, `ABCE`, `ABCF`... but it will never do something like `AABC`.

So basically, I need tuples or strings of characters that aren't repetitive (that is, a repetitive key can be cut in half to get two identical halves), but can contain duplicate characters. Good example: `AABABA`, not `AABAAB`.

How can I create such a collection that won't generate keys like this, and is lazily iterated so I don't blow up my RAM when I want to explore keys longer than 3 characters?

Comment: You mean "*can't* cut the key in half to get two identical halves"?

Comment: Maybe it sounds ambiguous but I mean to say that "repetitive" means that you can do such a thing.

Comment: It's not ambiguous, it's contradictory. First you say not repetitive (so `AABAAB` won't work), then you say you can cut the key in half and get two identical halves (so `AABAAB` *would* work). Your example supports the former. Just asking for clarification.

Comment: I think the OP means that `repetitive == can cut into equal halves` and that strings should not be repetitive, as the examples suggest.

Comment: I'll change it, in that case.

Comment: This is straightforwardly a two-step process: generate the possible sequences of values chosen from `{A, B, C, D}` (with repetitions, and distinguishing based on order), and then filtering out those which meet the "repetitive" condition. I assume it's clear how to implement the condition check, so the only remaining question here is about `itertools.product` - so I've closed this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
("".join(s) for s in product(alphabet, repeat=n) if s[:n//2]!=s[n//2:])
```

<sub>EDIT: fixed up thanks to @PetrViktorin</sub>

Comment: You can use `n` instead or `len(s)`. Also, use the `//` operator for integer division.

Comment: I get a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Is `alphabet` what you think it is? It should be an iterable e.g. a string or a list of characters.

Comment: I was using `string.ascii_uppercase` which I am pretty sure is an iterable.

Comment: It works for me. One of your names is not defined right: either `alphabet` is not an iterable or `product` is not `itertools.product`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`. On top of that, you can write a generator around that to filter out the ones you don't want.

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

Comment: +1. Very nice, never needed that although I use `itertools` frequently. Seems to be exactly what @agarett wants.

Comment: I see how it creates all the combinations but I don't know how to write such a generator. While iterating through keys I could just check to see if the first half equals the second half, but if that could be magically avoided I would prefer that.